react sequelize post adding values duplicate
I am using sequelize in combo with react to store, update and delete data in mysql.
Now I have users and some roles. And a table that stores the roleId and userId if a user has a specific role.
E.g.: I have a user that is an Admin and I want to update adding another role (Manager), but when I run the code, it adds another row with the roleId of the Admin role, eventhough a row with that roleId and userId is already inside the table. It should only add the extra roleId in the table.
I have a group of checkboxes that represent the roles. And at the moment Admin is pre-checked.
Below is the code that runs the post to add the roleId and UserId to the table:
Object.values(rightsValue).map(value => (
    axios.post("http://localhost:3001/userRoles", { RoleId: parseInt(value, 10), UserId: selectedUserIdEdit }).then((response) => {
        setShowRightsModal(false);
    })
));

rightsValue holds an object of IDs of the roles that are checked and I want those to be added to the table. It hold the value like:
[1, 2]

And the userId is: 1
So in the table it already shows:
RoleId      UserId
  1           1

It should become:
RoleId      UserId
  1           1
  2           1

But it shows:
RoleId      UserId
  1           1
  2           1
  1           1

Which should not be the case.

Anyone an idea?
